File upload field prevents submit handlers from being called
I have a node form that I'm modifying a bit in a form alter hook. I added an additional submit handler:
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = static::class . '::redirectAfterCreate';

Clicking on the "Save" button now runs the standard save functions and then my new function.
Then I added a second submit button:
  $form['back_button'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Back'),
  ];

I'm targetting this button in JavaScript, setting a hidden field before submitting the form. This is part of a multi-step form setup. The button should run the same submit functions, though.
Then I added a third way to submit the form, by clicking on another element. I submit the form in a JavaScript event handler like this:
document.getElementById('node-project-edit-form').submit();

This should also trigger the same submit handlers. All this works perfectly fine (under Drupal 10.2, by the way).
Problem: Now I added a file upload field through the node type's field and form display config. As soon as the field is part of the form, this setup stops working.
The main Save button still works and calls all the handlers. But the other buttons don't call the handlers anymore. The form simply reloads, without any error message, any PHP error in the log, any JavaScript error.
I search for an answer to this a lot. I tried to give the second submit button an individual name and even set the submit handlers explictely:
$form['back_button'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Back'),
  '#name' => 'go-back',
  '#submit' => $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'],
];

Still, no submit handler is called. This happens by the way, whether the form field is displayed or not (I'm setting parts of the form to #access = FALSE to get the multi-step effect). The file upload itself works.
Any idea what the problem could be or how to go about debugging this? I can't really be spending days for simply adding one file upload field...

I figured this out, and it is down to my design of the multistep form. No wonder nobody had an idea what was happening...
I did some more debugging and found that the form's submit handlers had been replaced with managed file submit handlers. From there, it was only a short way to FormBuilder line 1128, where the triggering element is retrieved from the form state. If it has its own validators or submit handlers set, those will be used instead of the global ones. The triggering element is set a couple of lines above in FormBuilder, where Drupal uses the first button if no button has been set as triggering element yet. So, previously when this ran and I didn't click on the Save button, this was selecting the Save button, it beeing the first button. Now, the upload button got in before that.
This leads to FormBuilder::handleInputElement, where the buttons of the form are registered and where Drupal tests whether a particular one has been clicked or not. I see the upload button here, as well as the default remove and save buttons, but not my two additional buttons!
So, in short: My problem was that I added the buttons in an #after_build function. I'm using this because of the field_groups module. I thought, grouping the fields into fieldsets and then hiding all fields of the not-current fieldset would make this easier. But the fieldsets are only present in the form array after the field group module's form_alter hook has run, and that always runs last. I could have changed the hook execution order, but instead chose to do my normal form alter stuff, then let the "field group" module's hook run and then do the final tweaking of the form #access for the form fields in an #after_build function.
The error was to add a new form element so late in the process! The FormBuilder class doesn't know about these buttons when building the form, so it also can't recognize that they have been clicked. I changed this now to always add a back and next button in the form alter hook. Then later in the #after_build function; i only hide them if they are not needed, just as with the rest of the form fields.
For anybody wondering how to debug this: I placed a break point in my submit handler which was called when I actually clicked the Save button. From there, this lead me to where the submit handlers are called, and I then could compare this with what happened when I clickd on the Back or Next button.
